# Django Error: Reverse for 'editpost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/editpost/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I get this error when trying to use the template that should link to the edit page.

I have seen someone do this using UpdateView but it gives the same error when i try it

here is some more relevant info
SO says i need to add more text so here is some more text (ignore this): more text more more text

templates:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="content_section">
    <div class="btn_container">
        <a class="new_post" href="{% url 'newpost' %}"><button class="new_post_btn">New Post</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="content_section_two">
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="post_short_container">
                <div class="title_container">
                
                    <a href="#" class="post_link">
                        <div><b>{{ product.title }}</b></div>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="right_btns">
                    <a href="{% url 'editpost' post.id %}" class="edit_link">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#" class="stats_link">Stats</a>
                    <div class="ad_btn_container">
                        <div class="ad_btn">Ad</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete_btn_container">
                        <div class="delete_btn">Delete</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('editpost/<int:pk>/', views.editPost, name='editpost'),
]
```

views.py

```
def editPost(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = NewPost(instance=post)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPost(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myposts')

    return render(request, 'create/new_post.html', {'form': form})
```

ListView:

```
def myPosts(request):

    context = {
         'products': Post.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'create/my_posts.html', context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'my_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

Comment: did you return ```post``` in your ```listPost``` view?

Comment: No, can you post an answer to show how i can add that

Comment: could you also show a little bit more info. on template? it looks like you have a for loop.

Comment: I have edited to show more

Comment: I have found out why i was looking for post.id when it actually needed product.id